# How to trigger 'custom emails' when a file is uploaded to SharePoint Online document library?

Tags: reactjs, email, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have SharePoint Online with multiple folders and sub-folders in the document library. Various files will be uploaded into these sub-folders at different times. I need a programmatic way to trigger automated custom emails sent out to different groups of individuals based on the file type and the folders the files are uploaded to.

I am new to this and need to know of various technologies that could be used. I know VBA and C#. However, it looks like the right technology might be React or PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Microsoft Flow workflow in SharePoint Online that will be running on events like add file. From MS Flow you can also send e-mails or call external api.

There are many MS Flow connectors to choose from, complete list you can find on MS Flow service page for SharePoint:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_sharepointonline/sharepoint/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft flow where you can use SharePoint trigger 'When a file is Created' then use 'Send an Email' action to send email notifications. Let me know if you need some more details about it.